# Array indexing by array-value and array-value dependant operation

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'm developing a finite-volume heat-transfer model in python with numpy. I've got a number of cells stacked vertically (for the next year a transfer to a 3d-model is planned) with each having a different temperature.

---

*To calculate the heat transfer between the cells, I need the thermal conductivity depending on the cell-temperature.
The thermal conductivity with its corresponding temperature (in degree Celsius) is stored in matrix `TC`, the cell-temperatures (in degree Celsius) are stored in vector (in the future in a matrix) `T_Cell`. These arrays look like:

```
TC = numpy.array([[0,569],[1,574],[2,582],[3,590],[4,598],[5,606],[6,613],[7,620]])
T_Cell  = numpy.array([[7],[5],[5],[4],[4],[3],[1],[0],[0]])
```

The temperatures in `TC` correspond to their row-index, so that accessing the thermal conductivity for example for a cell temperature of `T_Cell=5` can be done by indexing with the temperature (the value stored in T_Cell). Here shown for the cell with Index 2:

```
TC_Cell = TC[numpy.round(T_Cell[2]),1]
```

Resulting in `TC_Cell = 606`.
Is there an array-operation which allows me to get the cell's thermal conductivity (depending only on the cell's temperature) in an array with the same shape as `T_Cell`? For example with the arrays of `TC` and `T_Cell` as shown above:

```
TC_Cell = TC[T_Cell, 1]
```

So that the result for TC_Cell looks like:

`TC_Cell = array([[620],
       [606],
       [606],
       [598],
       [598],
       [590],
       [574],
       [569],
       [569]])`

Interpolation is NOT needed as I already interpolated the values in TC to a satisfying degree (not shown here to keep it clean, values in the array are also simplified and physically not correct).*

**I really don't know why, but suddenly it is working exactly like shown in my example... Maybe I had a typo somewhere in my code... :-/ Though my second question remains unresolved.**

---

My second question is:
I've got a differential equation with a solution which changes depending if one argument is zero or non-zero. This argument is depending on the cell, so it might be

```
Arg = numpy.array([[0.12],[0.9],[0],[0],[0.2]])
```

Currently my way to decide which solution to use is to run a for-loop over the `Arg`-vector (in the future: 3d-array) and to check if a cell is `0`. Like:

```
a=1
c=2
d=3
for cell in range(numpy.size(Arg, 0)):
    if Arg[cell, 0] != 0:
        # Solution1:
        Solution[cell] = (a / Arg[cell] + c) * numpy.e**(Arg[cell] * d) - (a / Arg[cell])
    elif Arg[cell, 0] == 0:
        # Solution2:
        Solution[cell] = a * d + c
```

With the result:

```
Solution = array([[  6.47773728],
   [ 45.18138759],
   [  5.        ],
   [  5.        ],
   [  7.7548316 ]])
```

Is there an array operation with which I can avoid using the for-loop?
**And to avoid further confusion due to missing information: `a` is also an array of the same size/shape as `Arg`:**

```
a = numpy.array([[1],[1],[1],[1],[1]])
```

(And the values are not necessarily `1`!)

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Boolean masking is the usual way of applying a calculation conditionally. `A[mask]=x1`, `A[~mask]=x2`, or sometimes `np.where(condition, x1, x2)`.

Comment: To make this question more inviting, you need to add a working example, something we can copy-n-paste and play with.  Trying get all the details right from a word description is too much work.

Comment: `sum(Arg==0) == 0` gives you a `True` if there's no `0`s. Or, if you want to replace all the 0-values by ones: `Arg[Arg==0]=1`

Comment: Thanks for your replies! @Swier: Yeah, but that doesn't help me with solving my equation. If there is a `0` in `Arg`, I still have to use Solution1 for the rest of the values in `Arg` and Solution2 for the `0`s. @hpaulj: I'm going to try this right now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
[a,b,c] = [1,2,3]
Arg = numpy.array([[0.12],[0.9],[0],[0],[0.2]])
Solution = Arg
Solution[Solution ==0] = 1
Solution = Solution * a * b * c
print(Solution)
```

returns:

```
[[ 0.72]
 [ 5.4 ]
 [ 6.  ]
 [ 6.  ]
 [ 1.2 ]]
```

Instead of trying to leave the `0` values in `Arg` out of the multipliation, just change them to `1`, which is neutral in multiplication, and thus has the same effect as avoiding multiplication.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unluckily the actual equation to solve is a little bit more complicated. I added a simplified minimalistic equation to my question which shows the basic structure. Sorry for having done that before!

Comment: @Scotty1- You can first make an array `results = numpy.zeros(len(Arg))` and then fill it in two steps: `results[Arg==0] = Equation1(Arg[Arg==0])` and then `results[Arg!=0] = Equation2(Arg[Arg!=0])`

Comment: Thanks alot Swier, that did it! I just tried it with hpaulj's solution with np.where before and that works as well... Just two more questions: If I switch to 2d-arrays (or 3d), which solution will work better and which one is faster?

Comment: I've been using boolean masking in matlab before but I didn't manage to do this in python... Looks like I still have to get used to python... :-/ Is there a way to also upvote hpaulj's answer?

Comment: numpy.where and mask arrays should be roughly equally fast. Though if your datasets become very large you might want to try looking into scipy and/or pandas and maybe pre-compile your script, but that's a whole other question. And to the top left of his comment should be a small arrow with which you can upvote.

Comment: Ok thanks! And after a small test both seem to be working with 3d-arrays... I already accepted your answer, but I can't upvote it because I don't have enough reputation. Thus I also cannot upvote hpaulj's answer...